# Oracle Datapump: Invalid operation at line 6224

Tags: oracle, plsql, datapump

I've a Oracle dump file that I'm trying to import to AWS RDS Oracle 12.1.0.2.v17
 database.

The dump file looks like this:

```
$ strings EXPDP.dmp | head -n 6
_|lM
"PACOPROD"."SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_01"
IBMPC/WIN_NT64-9.1.0
unicode
AL32UTF8
12.01.00.00.00
```

The commands I'm running is:

```
DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=>null, version=>'COMPATIBLE');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'EXPDP.dmp', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.ku$_file_type_dump_file);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(hdnl,'SCHEMA_EXPR','IN (''PACOPROD'')');
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;
/
```

The response is:

```
Error report -
ORA-39002: invalid operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 6224
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

The closes similar issue I've found is [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/209911/dbms-datapump-error-the-current-api-cannot-be-executed-because-of-inconsistenci), even though it's not exactly the same error message and in my case both source and target db is running 12.1.

I think the issue is one of the following:

- A) The DMP file is corrupt.
- B) I'm doing something wrong.

I've no clue how to get further though. Where shall I dig or what should I try to go forward?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a log file to the operation. It some times contain more information:

```
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( handle => hdnl, filename => 'EXPDP.log', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => dbms_datapump.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);
```